# Replace add to cart button with a custom button on WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I would like to replace the 'Add to cart' button for a specific product category and when product type isa a **`'simple product'`**.

I would like to do that on the page where I can see all the products (shop and archive pages) and in single product pages.

The code bellow just hide my add-to cart buttons from all post of my product category:

```
function western_custom_buy_buttons(){

   $product = get_product();

   if ( has_term( 'categ1', 'product_cat') ){

       // removing the purchase buttons

       remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );

       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

       remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );

       remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );

       remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );

       remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );

   }

}

add_action( 'wp', 'western_custom_buy_buttons' );
```

How can I achieve that? Any help please.

Comment: If you prefer using a plugin, here is one https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-add-to-cart-button-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 5):

Update: *Still Works in WooCommerce 8.2*

Here is a complete working solution that will replace all add-to-cart buttons for your defined product category and simple products only, by a custom **`"read more"`** button.

> **Note:** On some customized themes, the code will not work as the theme has already made changes to default WooCommerce behavior.

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 3+.

```
// Replacing add-to-cart button in shop pages and archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );

function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {

    // WooCommerce compatibility
    if ( method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
    } else {
        $product_id = $product->id;
    }

    if ( has_term( 'categ1', 'product_cat', $product_id ) && $product->is_type( 'simple') ) {
        // Set HERE your button link
        $link = get_permalink($product_id);
        $html = '<a href="'.$link.'" class="button alt add_to_cart_button">'.__("Read More", "woocommerce").'</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}

// Outputing a custom button in Single product pages (you need to set the button link)
function single_product_custom_button( ) {

    global $product;

    // WooCommerce compatibility
    if ( method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
    } else {
        $product_id = $product->id;
    }

    if ( has_term( 'categ1', 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        // Set HERE your button link
        $link = '#';
        echo '<a href="'.$link.'" class="button alt add_to_cart_button">'.__("Read More", "woocommerce").'</a>';
    }
}

// Replacing add-to-cart button in Single product pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'removing_addtocart_buttons', 1 );
function removing_addtocart_buttons()
{
    global $product;

    // WooCommerce compatibility
    if ( method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
    } else {
        $product_id = $product->id;
    }

    if ( has_term( 'categ1', 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
    {
        #### Removing the add-to-cart button ####

        ## Simple products
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );

        ## Other products types
        // remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
        // remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
        // remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
        // remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        // remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );


        #### Adding a custom replacement button ####

        ## Simple products
        add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'single_product_custom_button', 30 );

        ## Other products types
        // add_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'single_product_custom_button', 30 );
        // add_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'single_product_custom_button', 30 );
        // add_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'single_product_custom_button', 30 );
        // add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'single_product_custom_button', 30 );
        // add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'single_product_custom_button', 20 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Comment: Doesn't works on Wordpress 6.3 WooCommerce 7.5.1

Comment: Just tested the code… It still works on WooCommerce 8.2… But on some customized themes, the code will not work as the theme has already made changes to default WooCommerce behavior…